# Android encryption and decryption advise

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

I'm teaching my self jetpack compose and progressing nicely but have a hurdle i don't know how to jump just yet.

I've created a working encryption / decryption file that encrypts data before sending it to firebase realtime database. I successfully store the public and private keys in the android keyStore and it encrypts and decrypts just fine. What i can't get my head around is how this below scenario plays out.

In this example i have 3 users for simplicity. Sue, Bob and Mike

All three people log into the app. By doing so they create their own individual public and private keys. When Sue creates her profile and clicks save, the values for name: and emailAddress: are encrypted using her public key and the data then gets sent off to realtimeDatabase for storage.

Now, as this app is a geofencing type app the idea is that when sue enters the radius of Bob or Mike that they will see a notification that someone is nearby. They can then click on the map marker and view Sue's profile. However at this stage it's encrypted so Bob or Mike can't decrypt Sues profile to read it because their private key is not the keyPair that Sue used to encrypt the file.

How do i get Bob or Mike to be able to decrypt Sue's profile and view it ?

What i've tried (cause im a newbie and still learning about it all) is sharing Sues publicKey but that's pointless because it's the private key that does the decryption

I've also made a public and private key that is stored in a file of the app but since learnt that's not a good practice but it did work as intended, however i scraped that idea.

Having Bob request to Sue that he wants to read her profile and have Sue send the decrypted profile is not scaleable and doesn't seem efficent. So i'm curious how others approach this type of senario please ?

Secondly, If Sue logs in on another phone or clears her data, she will generate a new keyPair and therefore not be able to access her original decrypted profile when the app try's to download her profile and update the UI. Not sure how to approach that either ?

thanks

Comment: From the scenarios above it is still unclear what security model are you trying to achieve. From what I understand you want to have profiles encrypted in storage (and in transit) and you want to decrypt them on specific devices. What I was unable to understand is this, is Sue supposed to be the one determining who should be able to decrypt her profile and who should not? Or is some backend server supposed to determine which users can see her profile? You would want a type of key exchange, depending on encryption type and the trust model type, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange

Comment: Thanks for the comment, The app itself will determine who should see what profile.
The profile stored on firebase will have certain nodes that arn't encrypted. So for example If sue is a employee and Bob is a Employer, Sue wants to be a hairderesser and Bob wants to hire a hairdresser. Bobs app will retrieve all users from firebase, sort through ones that want to be a hairdresser and discard the rest. Bobs phone will then take all the profiles that want to be a hairdresser and decrypt their profiles so he can read some more info about Sue and whoever else etc.